# django template tag in static js files

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to use template tag and variables in static js files.

I'll give you 3 files.
no1_ index.html
no2_ inc/index.html
no3_ index javascript file

no1 file is template. html tags in here.
and it refers to no2.file to include some scripts.

no2.file has some kinds of script includes.
and it refers to no3.file to make my own scripts.

in no3.file, I want to deal with my template variables from view.py
but at no3.file, It can not read template tags and variables.
what can I do for this issue?

no1_index.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load mathfilters %}
{% extends 'mobileWeb/base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% include 'mobileWeb/inc/index/index.html' %}

    <div id="map" style="width:80%;height:300px; margin:20px auto; border-radius: 10px;"></div>

    <div style="width:90%; margin:auto">
        <!-- this row will wrapping foreach-->

        {% for mart in marts %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5" onclick="martClick({{ mart }})">
                    {% with "/mobileWeb/images/"|add:mart.imageFileNo|add:".png" as path %}
                        <img src="{% static path %}" style="width:120px; height:120px; margin-top:10px;">
                        <br>
                        <h3>{{ mart.name }}</h3>
                    {% endwith %}
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-7" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#martModal"
                     data-whatever="{{ mart.id }}_{{ mart.name }}">
                    {% for item in items %}
                        {% if mart.id == item.mart %}
                            <div>
                                <h4 style="color:mediumpurple;">{{ item.name }}</h4>
                                {% if item.discountPrice == 1 or item.discountPrice == 100 %}
                                    <h6><span
                                            style="color:red">{{ item.originalPrice|sub:item.discountPrice|div:item.originalPrice|mul:100|floatformat:"0" }}% 할인</span>
                                    </h6>
                                {% else %}
                                    <h6>할인판매가 : {{ item.discountPrice }}원 <span
                                            style="color:red">{{ item.originalPrice|sub:item.discountPrice|div:item.originalPrice|mul:100|floatformat:"0" }}% 할인</span>
                                    </h6>
                                {% endif %}

                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- Mart Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="martModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Item Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="itemModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="itemModal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="itemModal-title" id="itemModal-title" onclick="purchaseItem()"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemModal-body" id="itemModal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="stopTimer()">취소
                        </button>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

no2 inc/index.html

```
{% load static %}

<!-- outter module-->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-159115722-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-159115722-1');
</script>

<!-- kakao map -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=2a40b9e58744cbe7d0cb367e51c07eb4"></script>


<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mobileWeb/css/index/index.css' %}">

<!--js-->
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'mobileWeb/js/index/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

no3 index javascript file

```
        function writeMartModal(martId, martName) {
            console.log("martID : " + martId);
            document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML = '';


            document.getElementById('modal-title').innerHTML = martName;
            {% for item in items %}
                var itemMartId = {{ item.mart }};
                if (martId == itemMartId) {
                    var itemId = {{ item.id }};
                    var itemName = '{{ item.name }}';
                    var itemPrice = {{ item.discountPrice }};
                    var itemExpirationDate = '{{ item.expirationDate|date:"m월d일 H시 i분 까지" }}';
                {% autoescape off %}
                    var itemComment = '{{ item.comment }}';
                {% endautoescape %}
                    var html = "";
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    html += `
                    <div>
                    <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemModal" data-whatever="${martName}_${itemId}_${itemName}">
                        <h4 style = "color:mediumpurple;" > ${itemName} </h4>
                    <h6> ${itemPrice}원 </h6>
                    <h6> ${itemExpirationDate} </h6>
                    </div>
                    {% autoescape off %}
                    <h6 style="color:red">${itemComment}</h6>
                    {% endautoescape %}
                    </div>
                `
                    div.innerHTML = html;
                    document.getElementById('modal-body').appendChild(div);
                }

            {% endfor %}
        };
```

errors in javascript file
[image]

Comment: JS files are not processed by Django template engine.

Comment: than how can I separate js files from django template? is there only one way makes js script in django template together? since I'm the beginner, I don't know what the universal way is.